# VBAとIEの操作

Tags: vba

```
<a href="" onclick="return csvDownload();"
           onmouseout="chgImg('/misc/csv.gif','csv');"
           onmouseover="chgImg('/misc/csv_on.gif','csv');">
<img src="/misc/csv.gif" width="106" height="19" alt="CSVダウンロード"     
     title="CSVダウンロード" border="0" name="csv"></a>
```

上記のhtmlのコードがあり、マクロでそのボタンを押したいですが、
どうした方がいいでしょうか？

Comment: そのページはどのように表示されるのでしょうか。例えば、マクロ実行前から起動しているIE上で表示されているとか、VBAから `CreateObject('InternetExplorer.Application')` として起動したとか。

Comment: VBA なのでどの Ofice ソフトからの操作ですか
または,IEに積まれているスクリプト言語である VBS ことを言っているのですか

Answer (score 0):

こことか、こことかですかね。(下記URL)

再現できるサイトとか、ソースとかがあれば、動作確認できますが、
そうじゃないと、アドバイスしにくいです。

VBAでIEのtagクリックサブルーチン化 | IE操作の自動化
http://www.vba-ie.net/form/subroutine-tagclick.html

画像をクリックする - VBAによるIE自動制御
http://vba-code.net/ie/click-an-image/